# Dlib SVM predict and distance

Tags: c++, object-detection, dlib

I using this example code [FHOG Object Detector](http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html) from Dlib. It's possible to get prediction and distance (probability of class) of sample? I want to generate a ROC curve from distances of samples.

(Like in OpenCV CvSVM::predict)

Comment: have you take a look at this example code? http://dlib.net/svm_pegasos_ex.cpp.html

Comment: yes, of course. I tried to set typenames on dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid or pyramid_down and nothing worked